# Excel add text to a cell instead of overwrite

Tags: excel, vba

Hiho

I have exported a File from a DB and have to set cretira. To check if the tickets are correct. 
If one is false, I have to write the false part in a cell.

My problem:
How can I add a sentence to a cell instead of overwrite the whole cell.

For example:

The Phone number and Name is false.

Actual state:

"Please enter a valid Name."

Target state:

"Please enter a valid Phone number. Please enter a valid Name."

My approach is to reserve a cell for each possible wrong cell. And assemble them in one cell.

Is there a better solution without VBA?

Thanks

RafnexJr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using VBA, you can use 99moorem's response. But if you want to use Excel formulas, use the If statement. If you have data in A1, a formula for B2, for example, would be something like this:

```
=If(A1 <> "Name",A1 & "is false.","")
```

This checks cell A1 to see if it says 'Name'. If it does not, cell B2 says '[A1 value] is false.' If it does say 'Name', B2 is blank.

Answer (score 1):

range("A1").value = range("A1").value & " AMMEND ME ON END"

try above

You just need to include itself in what you are putting in the cell